# Find a new angle of the ball when it bounces (using coordinates)

Tags: c++, math, sfml, trigonometry

I have a game where a ball is bouncing off walls. It's on a coordinate plane. I want there to be some small amount of randomness when it bounces to keep the game more interesting. How would I do this while keeping the ball at a constant speed the whole time? Right now my code means it only bounces at right angles.

The top left corner of the window is 0,0 and the bottom right is winW,winH (set at 800,800 right now).

ball.cpp snippet

```
pos.x = start.x;
pos.y = start.y;

speed.x = .4f; // the f indicates that it's per frame. 
speed.y = .4f;

void Ball::hitLeftRight() {
    speed.x = -speed.x;
}

void Ball::hitTopBottom() {
    speed.y = -speed.y;
}

void Ball::reset() {
   // for a new level in game
   pos.x = start.x;
   pos.y = start.y;
}    

void Ball::update() {
    // called every frame
    pos.y += speed.y;
    pos.x += speed.x;

    ballShape.setPosition(pos);
}
```

Comment: ...by adding a random generated number that is clamped?

Comment: The speed and the reflection angle are independent, so what ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a random angle to the ball in addition to just flipping the velocities. By using the `<random>` header and generating values between 0 and 2 * pi you can add a random velocity in any direction. Or as in the example below, limiting it to -22.5 to 22.5 degrees. Or `pi / 8.0` radians.

## Random Angle

You could of course tweak those values based on the angle of impact, but that is implementation specific. Below is an example on how you could generate such numbers:

```
#include <random>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    constexpr double pi = 3.14159;
    constexpr double bounceSpeed = 5.0;

    std::random_device seed;
    std::mt19937 generator(seed());

    // Numbers between - pi / 2 and pi / 8 gives angles between -22.5 and 22.5
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> random(-pi / 8.0, pi / 8.0);

    double deltaX = cos(random(generator)) * bounceSpeed;
    double deltaY = sin(random(generator)) * bounceSpeed;

    std::cout << deltaX << "\n" << deltaY << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Afterwards, you could add `deltaX` and `deltaY` to your respective `x` and `y` velocities.

## Plain Random

Or if you're satisfied with just any purely random velocity:

```
// Generate random double in range [min, max]
double uniform(double min, double max) {
    static std::random_device seed;
    static std::mt19937 generator(seed());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> random(min, max);
    return random(generator);
}
```

Call that function twice with the velocity range you desire, and add that to the `x` and `y` of your ball.

## Keeping Speed

To keep the speed of the ball you could normalize the velocity vector and then multiply it by the desired speed of you ball after adding the random velocity.

To normalize, divide by length:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    
    constexpr double speed = 4.0;

    double x = 3.0;
    double y = 4.0;

    double length = sqrt(x * x + y * y);

    x /= length;
    y /= length;

    x *= speed;
    y *= speed;

    std::cout << x << "\n" << y << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Then multiply by speed to keep it consistent.

Comment: you want to generate one number, not 2

Comment: how does the 'keeping speed' part fit into the 'random angle' part. Are x and y supposed to be deltaX and deltaY?

Answer (score 0):

To start, have a set speed for the ball as a float. Then have a velocity which you move by every update with x and y members like what you have now. Calculate how far you move x and y using your speed, your angle of movement, and some trigonometry. (Remember to convert degrees to radians)

```
float Speed = 10;
float Angle = 45;
Velocity.x = cos(Angle * 3.14159 / 180) * Speed;
Velocity.y = sin(Angle * 3.14159 / 180) * Speed;
```

Whenever you encounter a collision, you can then recalculate your angle add your new random angle and recalculate your velocity. (Again converting degrees to radians).

```
//if (collision)
Angle = atan2(Velocity.y * 3.14159 / 180, Velocity.x * 3.14159 / 180);
Angle += rand() % 90 + 1; // Could also be subtracting here
Velocity.x = cos(Angle * 3.14159 / 180) * Speed;
Velocity.y = sin(Angle * 3.14159 / 180) * Speed;
```

Add or subtract from the angle based on what side you have struck and from what angle.

```
void HitTop()
{
    if (Velocity.x > 0)
        //Subtract random angle
    else
        //Add random angle
}
```

Do this for all sides.

Answer (score 0):

Let your border has arbitrary form (not only rectangle). If border normal (unit) vector in bouncing points is

```
n = (n.x, n.y)
```

then speed vector after bouncing changes:

```
    dot = speed.x * n.x + speed.y * n.y

    //after reflection
    newspeed.x = speed.x - 2 * dot * n.x
    newspeed.y = speed.y - 2 * dot * n.y
```

To add some randomness, just rotate normal  by small random angle:

```
df = GaussianRandom(Mean = 0, Sigma = Pi / 30)  //arbitrary parameter
            //seems in c++ it is std::normal_distribution
n'.x = n.x * Cos(df) - n.y * Sin(df)
n'.y = n.x * Sin(df) + n.y * Cos(df)
```

and use `n'` to calculate reflection. Note that this approach preserves speed magnitude.